# Except for other conditions: HZ is smaller, process schedule is less accurate?

Tags: linux-kernel

Except for other conditions: HZ is smaller, process schedule is less accurate?
HZ definition in "arch/arm/include/asm/param.h":

```
#ifdef __KERNEL__
# define HZ     CONFIG_HZ   /* Internal kernel timer frequency */
# define USER_HZ    100     /* User interfaces are in "ticks" */
# define CLOCKS_PER_SEC (USER_HZ)   /* like times() */
#else
# define HZ     100
#endif
```

Comment: How "process schedule" should be less accurate you think?

Comment: The clock is just a reference for timing calculations, doesn't make a scheduler less or more accurate.

Comment: With higher HZ scheduler may be called more often, but the basic scheduling time unit, the `timeslice` is same for most `HZ`s: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.12/kernel/sched.c#L78  "Minimum timeslice is 5 msecs (or 1 jiffy, whichever is larger), default timeslice is 100 msecs, maximum timeslice is 800 msecs.", `define DEF_TIMESLICE           (100 * HZ / 1000)`